# Meteor: Input data to a new collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to insert some elements into a Collection. It is my first attempt to use Meteor/MongoDB. So I don't see, what I'm doing wrong with this.
When I try  so save a new title, I get the error

> "Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for
>   method 'insert'. [403]"

**Template:**

```
<template name="casuistry">
    <div class="create">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
            <button>Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**collections.es6.js**

```
Casuistry = new Mongo.Collection('casuistry')
Casuistry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {type: String},
  caseNumber: {type: Number, defaultValue: 0},
  htmlContent: {type: String, defaultValue: '[]'},
}))
```

**casuistry.es6.js**

```
Template.casuistry.events({
  'submit .create form' (e, t) {
    var title = t.val('title')
    Casuistry.insert({title}, (err, _id) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
      }
      t.val('title', '')
      Router.go('casuistry', {_id})
    })
    return false
  }
})
```

Comment: Sounds like some publication issues. Since you're in development, you should have autopublish enabled. Did you remove it? If so, then you must create a 'publication' or 'subscription'. Try running your code from the submit callback in the meteor console by running 'meteor console' from the command line. If it works, then this is an access issue

Comment: As I'm using an example-app, which I want to extend (for learning how meteor works), I've added the parts shown above. So a similar module is working in the example app, but this new parts added by myself doesn't work and I don't understand why. I added `Meteor.subscribe('casuistry')` but that doesn't help either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to insert into the collection from the client-side. Without the [`insecure`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/insecure) package you have to first define what is allowed and what is not allowed server-side - to make sure that users don't just insert/remove/update whatever they want.

You can either use [`allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow)/[`deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) or use [`methods`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) (highly recommended!). I'm not going to go too deep on methods vs. allow/deny, [there are good blog posts available on this topic](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/), but in general: allow/deny is hard to get right and you just have more control in a method.

Something to note is that you can also define client-side collections by passing `null` into the constructor:

```
var clientCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

In this case, you'd use the Collection exactly like you did - because it's  a client-side only collection, there is no reason to worry about someone tampering with your "real" data.

Comment: As I'm right now in the "developing mode" I didn't remove the insecure-package right now. So I don't think, that this is a problem at the moment...

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I'm using `null`, everything is working. So I have to use some methods, right?

Comment: @user3142695 It works, because there's no server-side check on it. If you use the actual collection name, Meteor wants you to validate that the user is allowed to insert the data; otherwise someone evil could take over your DB. You can either use methods (recommended) or just define allow/deny rules for the insert function on the collection. I'd highly suggest looking at the linked blog post, it's almost a must-read.